# Error with bundler deploying Ruby on Rails app in DigitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, digital-ocean

Im trying to deploy an app in a DigitalOcean Ubuntu 14.04 x32 Droplet with apache2 and Passenger, everything works fine until I open the IP adress of my droplet, It shows a passenger page with this error message:

```
Web application could not be started

cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:278:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:381:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:276:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:99:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:157:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

I don't know why the problem originates but Im desesperate, I been searched a lot about this problem but none of the solutions I found works for me :(

Comment: Maybe misconfigured  `passenger_root`? or bundler not installed?

Comment: in wich file is suppossed to be the passenger_root line? Because if I run the command  bundler -v , It returns bundler 1.8.5 so I don´t think is bundler, or maybe I installed it wrong

Comment: It should be in on of your apache conf files. The one you can run on command line is different from the one the web server(Apache) uses. What was your method to install Ruby and Passenger?

Comment: using wget , I followed the instructions in this tutorial

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04